# Querying two related Oracle tables at once with ROracle package

Tags: sql, r, oracle, roracle

I have a functional SQL query that pulls data from two related tables in an Oracle database that looks like this (dummy query):

```
SELECT
OP.FIELD_1 AS "Trade Date",
L.FIELD_2 AS "Node ID"

FROM
TABLE_1 OP,
TABLE_2 L

WHERE
OP.FIELD_1 = '12-JAN-2019'
```

Is it possible to use this query within the ROracle framework? I cannot get it to work and I do not know if it is because it is not possible, I am formatting the query incorrectly, etc. I have tried a number of things, but here is an example of something I tried (dummy query):

```
library(ROracle) 

# Connect to database 
con <- dbConnect(drv, username = "username",
             password = "pass",
             dbname = "database_name")

# Query the database
res <- dbSendQuery(con "SELECT OP.FIELD_1 AS Trade Date,
                              L.FIELD_2 AS Node ID
                       FROM TABLE_1 OP,
                            TABLE_2 L
                       WHERE OP.FIELD_1 = '12-JAN-2019'")
```

My database connection works fine and I can query from either one of these tables, but not together in this format. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated! The ROracle documentation contains only very simple query examples.

Comment: Any compliant query in connecting databasse can work in `dbSendQuery`. What error are you receiving? Also, I assume the missed quotes around SQL statement are a typo in this post.

Comment: Thanks I fixed the quotes - the error on this example is:  Error: unexpected string constant in:  FROM TABLE_1 OP, TABLE_2 L WHERE OP.FIELD_1 = '12-JAN-2019'". But if you have an example of a functional query using this package that does what I am seeking to do, I would be very grateful to see it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply escape your double quotes around column aliases since you use double quotes for R string. Oracle throws an error for space between *Node ID*.

```
res <- dbSendQuery(con, "SELECT OP.FIELD_1 AS \"Trade Date\",
                              L.FIELD_2 AS \"Node ID\"
                         FROM TABLE_1 OP,
                              TABLE_2 L
                         WHERE OP.FIELD_1 = '12-JAN-2019'")
```

Alternatively, wrap R string in single quotes and escape single quotes in `WHERE`:

```
res <- dbSendQuery(con, 'SELECT OP.FIELD_1 AS "Trade Date",
                              L.FIELD_2 AS "Node ID"
                         FROM TABLE_1 OP,
                              TABLE_2 L
                         WHERE OP.FIELD_1 = \'12-JAN-2019\'')
```

Still more, simply avoid spaces in your column aliases requiring the use of double quotes in Oracle:

```
res <- dbSendQuery(con, "SELECT OP.FIELD_1 AS Trade_Date,
                              L.FIELD_2 AS Node_ID
                         FROM TABLE_1 OP,
                              TABLE_2 L
                         WHERE OP.FIELD_1 = '12-JAN-2019'")
```

Even **better** [parameterize](https://db.rstudio.com/best-practices/run-queries-safely/#interpolation-by-hand) your query with `DBI::sqlInterpolate` and avoid *any* quote escapes. Below also uses `CROSS JOIN` the more explicit, preferred version than comma separated tables:

```
library(ROracle) 
library(DBI)

...
sql <- sqlInterpolate(con, "SELECT OP.FIELD_1 AS Trade_Date,
                                   L.FIELD_2 AS Node_ID
                            FROM TABLE_1 OP
                            CROSS JOIN TABLE_2 L
                            WHERE OP.FIELD_1 = ?param",
                      param = "12-JAN-2019")

res <- dbGetQuery(con, sql)
```

Comment: Thanks for the thorough and functional response!